# Local Storage on a to do list

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is a typical todo list. Items can be added or removed,it works like this but unfortunately when I refresh it disappears. I wanted to use the localStorage functionality to solve the issue. I managed to create an array where to store the items. Now I want to show in the browser the items stored in `tasks`. I've got stuck when I load `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getTasks)` and in particular `getTasks()`. I have set `console.log('bonjour')`, to test it and it does not go through.

Thank you, as always

```js
function getTasks() {
    console.log('bonjour')

    let tasks;
        if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
            tasks = [];
        } else {
            tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
        }
        tasks.forEach(task => {
            const html = `
            <li>
                <span>${task}</span>
                <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
            </li>`
            list.innerHTML += html;
            console.log('hi')
        });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Todolist</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" class="add">
        <h1>To do list</h1>
        
        <input type="text" id="name" name="add" placeholder="Enter name here"> 
     
    </form>

    <ul class="todos">
        <li>
            <span>marco</span>
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
        </li> 
    </ul>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try document.addEventListener("load",  getTasks) or window.addEventListener("load",  getTasks)

Comment: Do you mean document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getTasks) cannot go into getTasks method? Or you are asking the localStorage not working properly

Comment: Since he has a `console.log` at the start that also doesnt fire it seems like the whole `getTasks` function doesnt get called

Comment: It should be fired as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/198xso4z/

Comment: @huanfeng the whole thing I guess

Comment: You're not saving your items in `localStorage`

Comment: @Matteo: where are you running your code? on local machine or at some place like `codesandbox` etc?

Comment: @AdityaParab local machine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getTasks() {
  console.log('bonjour')

  let tasks
  if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
    tasks = []
  } else {
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))
  }
  let list = document.getElementById('theList')
  tasks ? .forEach((task) => {
    const html = `
              <li>
                  <span>${task}</span>
                  <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
              </li>`
    list.innerHTML += html
    console.log('hiiiii')
  })
}

function storeValue(val) {
  if (!val) return
  if (!localStorage.getItem('tasks')) {
    let tasks = []
    tasks.push(val)
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
    getTasks()
  } else {
    let tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))
    tasks.push(val)
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
    getTasks()
  }
}

getTasks()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Todolist</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <form action="" class="add"> -->
  <h1>To do list</h1>

  <input type="text" id="name" name="add" placeholder="Enter name here" onchange="storeValue(this.value)">

  <!-- </form> -->

  <ul class="todos" id="theList">
    <li>
      <span>marco</span>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the solution try it on your local system here you will get an error so it is better to test on your own system. Also clean up the code I just resolved the issue

Comment: Unfortunately still does not fire console.log('bonjour'). I have also found an error on line11, but even if fixed, the error persists

Comment: can you tell me please where are you testing

Comment: VS Code and Chrome. 

The problem is that when item1 is added, it is ok. Then when item2 is added, the code add again item1 and item2. When item3 is added, the code added item1, item2 and item3 and so forth..

Out of curiosity what is the porpouse of onchange="storeValue(this.value) in the input? Many thanks